# Problem Embedding Angle into TikZ Pic

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-angles

I am trying to create a `pic` that includes an angle `pic` from the angles library using TikZ. The error I get is

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [grouping levels=255].
<argument> ...kz@pp@name {x1}\endcsname }{center}{
                                                  \pgfsettransform {\csname ...
l.18 ...pic text=$\alpha$] {my angle={x1}{x2}{x3}}
                                                  ; % does not work
If you really absolutely need more capacity,
you can ask a wizard to enlarge me.
```

I have not been able to resolve this issue. How can I draw the angle within my own pic?

Here's the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \tikzset{
            pics/my angle/.style n args={3}{
                code = {
                    \draw (#1) -- (#2) -- (#3);
                    \pic [draw] {angle=#1--#2--#3}; % offending line
                }
            }
        }
        
        \coordinate (x1) at (-1, 0);
        \coordinate (x2) at (0, 0);
        \coordinate (x3) at (-0.5, -0.5);
        \pic[pic text=$\alpha$] {my angle={x1}{x2}{x3}}; % does not work
        
%        \pic [draw] {angle=x1--x2--x3}; % this does draw the angle
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the `angle` pic works with `foreground code` and `background code`, and this does for some reason not like to get nested into a "normal" `code`. However, you can use e.g. `foreground code` to nest the `angle` pic in your `my angle` pic.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \tikzset{pics/my angle/.style n args={3}{
                setup code  ={},
                background code ={},
                foreground code = {\pic [draw] 
                        {angle=#1--#2--#3}; % no longer offending 
                },
                code = {
                    \draw (#1) -- (#2) -- (#3);
                }
            }
        }
        
        \coordinate (x1) at (-1, 0);
        \coordinate (x2) at (0, 0);
        \coordinate (x3) at (-0.5, -0.5);
        \pic[pic text=$\alpha$] 
        {my angle={x1}{x2}{x3}}; %  works now
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This solved my problem. As a side note, the arrow head setting that I used in the angle becomes the default line style for the rest of the lines in the `code` section. You can see this by changing `[draw]` to `[draw,->]` in the `foreground code`.

Comment: @DavidMarshall Thanks for the heads up! You may play with the `pic actions` to selectively affect certain paths in your pic. However, I have never done that for nested pics, so I don't know if this is a helpful comment.